# RESTful C# WCF Post to function

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have created a very simple RESTful web service using C#. I have an ADO.NET Entity Model and a WCF Data Service. This is working fine for retrieving information on my remote application. I am now however trying to create a RESTful function that reacts to posted data and adds it into my database. Here is the code I have so far to share the data:

```
namespace WcfService10
{
    public class GetInformation : DataService<DBLocalEntities>
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
            // Examples:
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("users", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
            // config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("MyServiceOperation", ServiceOperationRights.All);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        }
    }
}
```

In order to add a way of processing posted information to my restful service, how would I go about this? Is it as simple as adding a WCF Service or should it be different in order to work via REST?

Comment: Consider using Web API for REST instead of using WCF

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If so, please update

Answer (score 0):

Modify your entity access rule setting to:

```
 config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("users", EntitySetRights.All);
```

In your client code, you can add an item to the entity just like we do in EF.

```
DBLocalEntities client = new DBLocalEntities(URI);
User newUser = new User()
    {
        //Set values to properties
    }
client.AddTousers(newUser);
client.SaveChanges();
```

This will automatically generate appropriate URI to post data. It is done in RESTful way, but the HTTP methods are abstracted from us. You can also modify and delete values just like EF.